# How do I view my profile?

Tags: dota-2

To view someone else's profile, I can click them and select "View Dota 2 Profile". My own profile doesn't show up in my friend's list though so I can't find a way to view it. I've tried clicking my avatar up above that, but it doesn't seem to do anything. Is there a way to view my own?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click your name in the upper right. That's it.

[image]

Alternatively, use http://dotabuff.com/ to find your profile and view your recent games. It's a very useful site.

Comment: Ah, my name, not my picture. Now I feel dumb. Thanks.

Comment: i think picture used to work too but it doesnt anymore =(

Comment: If you're not listed, you need to enable `Expose Public Match Data`. See [this link](http://www.dotabuff.com/pages/enabling-statistics)