# How can I check my statistics in Dota 2

Tags: dota-2

How can I get statistics in Dota 2 such as hit/loss ratio, what skill level do I have (not the Battle Points) and such figures.

One very interesting metric would be the win/loss ratio in function of what items you bought for each hero.

Is there an independent website providing these kind of statistics ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dotabuff](http://dotabuff.com/) will give you detailed information on your win/loss ratio, and K/D ratio, even breaking it down by hero and match. However it requires you to [enable public statistics](http://dotabuff.com/pages/enabling-statistics), and it can't get any level or Battle Points info.

The easier way is to just to [view your own profile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106317/how-do-i-view-my-profile) inside of Dota 2. It will give you your level and your number of wins and losses.

Dotabuff doesn't show items' win/loss ratios personalized, [although you can view overall item effects](http://dotabuff.com/items), but I don't think that there are any other websites to do any of this.